Не удается найти имя "defineNuxtPlugin". VS code подсвечивает красным Nuxt
Такая проблема, в VS code думает что в коде ошибки, хотя все работает, код скопирован в мануала.
Проект на Nuxt


Не удается найти имя "defineNuxtPlugin"

плагины для Vue и тд установлены. Перезагружал и VS code и компьютер - не помогло.
файл tsconfig.json есть


Попробуйте добавить: import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app' в начале файла.
